# Dictionary to a nested list, or an ordered list to a nested list

Tags: python

I have a list of ints that I am trying to turn into a nested list, either using comprehensions or a for loop. I have tried a few methods and done plenty of research but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
original = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

From the original list I managed to create the following nested list and dictionary,

```
first_try = [[1], [2], [3], [3], [4], [5], [6], [6], [6], [7], [8], [9], [9]]

d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2}
```

Desired output is:

```
final = [[1], [2], [3,3], [4], [5], [6,6,6], [7], [8], [9,9]]
```

Any tips or advice?

Answer (score 1):

This produces the output you're looking for in one line:

```
import itertools

original = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
final = [list(grp[1]) for grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(original))]
# [[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

However, the dict you've gotten to is only one step away from the output you want:

```
d = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2}
final = [[k] * v for (k, v) in sorted(d.items())]
# [[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do the following from your original list:

```
from collections import Counter

original = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]

counts = Counter(original)
result = [[k]*counts[k] for k in sorted(counts)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

If you fancy a one-liner (after importing Counter) you could do:

```
original = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
result = [[k for _ in range(v)] for k, v in sorted(Counter(original).items())]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried a similar method but wasn't quite there!

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do it (more or less efficiently):

```
original = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

**using dictionary indexing** *O(NlogN) if output sorted, O(N) if not sorted*

```
d = dict()
for v in sorted(original):
    d.setdefault(v,[]).append(v)

print(d)
{1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4], 5: [5], 6: [6, 6, 6], 7: [7], 8: [8], 9: [9, 9]}

print(list(d.values()))
[[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

**using groupby from itertools** *O(NlogN)*

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(original))]

[[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

**brute force counting distinct values** *O(N^2)*

```
[[v]*original.count(v) for v in sorted({*original})]]  

[[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

**Counter from collections** *O(NlogN) if output sorted, O(N) if not sorted*

```
from collections import Counter

sorted([v]*c for v,c in Counter(original).items()) 

[[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```

**binary search/insertion** *O(NlogN)*

```
from bisect import bisect_left
keys   = []         # ordered values (keys to position of groups)
groups = []         # resulting value groups aligned with keys
for v in original:
    i = bisect_left(keys,v)           # position of group
    if i==len(keys) or keys[i] != v:  # new group if not same key
        keys.insert(i,v)              # add to keys 
        groups.insert(i,[v])          # new group 
    else:
        groups[i].append(v)           # append to existing group

print(groups)
[[1], [2], [3, 3], [4], [5], [6, 6, 6], [7], [8], [9, 9]]
```